# Solving : $ \left(1+x^{2}\right) \frac{d y}{d x}+2 x y=4 x^{2} $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the following ODE : $$
\left(1+x^{2}\right) \frac{d y}{d x}+2 x y=4 x^{2}
$$

After rearrangement I get : $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{4x^{2}-2xy}{1+x^{2}}$$ please help me after this step.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}$

This is a linear DE. Rearranging this we have that
\begin{align*}
&\frac{\d y}{\d x} + \frac{2x}{1 + x^2}\cdot y = \frac{4x^2}{1 + x^2}\\
\implies&\frac{\d y}{\d x} + P(x)\cdot y = Q(x)
\end{align*}
Now the integrating factor is $$ I =  e^{\int{{2x}/{1 + x^2}}dx} =  e^{{{\ln(1 + x^2)}}} = 1 + x^2$$
On multiplication by the integrating factor and on integrating we obtain [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor)
$$y \cdot I = \int Q(x) \cdot I dx + C  $$
And on substitution of $I$, we have that
\begin{align*}
&~y (1 + x^2) = \int 4x^2 + C\\
\implies &~ y \cdot (1 + x^2) = \frac{4}{3} \cdot x^3 + C
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

Don't rearrange like that. Do integrating factor method instead.

Indeed, the left side is the product rule for $(\mu y)'$ for some function $\mu(x)$... can you see what $\mu$ is?

Comment: I think $\mu$ will be $(1+{x}^{2})\cdot{y}$

Comment: I got it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(1+x^{2}\right) \frac{d y}{d x}+2 x y=4 x^{2}$$
$$\left((1+x^2)y\right)'=4x^2$$
Integrate.